# SQL Stored Procedure on Transaction mismatch

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure where as an error hits it should rollback everything, i kept looking but i couldnt find the error that keep pops out.

> [Exception: An unexpected SQL error occurred at source '.Net SqlClient Data Provider' with error number 266.16.2 in procedure 'ST_IV_ItemPrice.SP_Insert' at line 130. Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.]

I hope i could get some help here.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ST_IV_ItemPrice.SP_Insert]
    /*parameters*/
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID(''tempdb..#tempPriceList'') IS NOT NULL
        /*Then it exists*/
        DROP TABLE #tempPriceList
    CREATE TABLE #tempPriceList(PriceListid int, NewCurrencyUnitPrice     decimal(19, 5))

    DECLARE @Error int,
        @NextListid int,
        @NewCurrencyUnitPrice decimal(19, 5),
        @NoRounding int = 0,
        @UserSpecified int = 4



    BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    BEGIN TRY
        /*Insert item to table*/

        SET @Id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
        SET @Error = @@ERROR


        IF @Error = 0 AND @AutoGenerate = 1
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #tempPriceList(PriceListid, NewCurrencyUnitPrice)
            VALUES(@Id, @Price) 

            WHILE(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #tempPriceList))
            BEGIN


            SELECT TOP 1 @NextListid = [id], @NewCurrencyUnitPrice =      [NewCurrencyUnitPrice]
            FROM #tempPriceList

            /*INSERT SELECT STATEMENT*/

            INSERT INTO #tempPriceList ([PriceListid],[NewCurrencyUnitPrice])
            Select [ListId] , [NewCurrencyUnitPrice]


            IF @Error = 0 AND @SetExpiredDate = 1 AND @FromDate IS NOT NULL
            BEGIN
            /*Update item that is same as inserted and set to inactive*/


            END

            DELETE FROM #tempPriceList WHERE PriceListid = @NextListid

        END 
    END 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION    
    END CATCH

    IF @@TRANCOUNT>0
        COMMIT TRANSACTION  

    RETURN @Error
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ST_IV_ItemPrice.SP_Insert]
    /*parameters*/
AS
BEGIN
    /* don't drop what does not belong to you */
    CREATE TABLE #tempPriceList(PriceListid int, NewCurrencyUnitPrice     decimal(19, 5))

    BEGIN TRY
        /* begin/commit within a single code block */
        BEGIN TRANSACTION 

        /* some code */

        /* we are here if everything is ok */
        COMMIT TRANSACTION  
    END 
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        /* check xact_state instead of @@trancount, because @@trancount may be >0 whilst you are unable to commit/rollback anything */
        IF XACT_STATE() IN (-1, 1)
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

        /* do not suppress exceptions! */
        RAISERROR(...)
    END CATCH

    /* it will be dropped after you leave SP scope, but you may clean all created here by yourself; this is not required */
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempPriceList') IS NOT NULL
        EXEC('DROP TABLE #tempPriceList')

    RETURN @Error
END
```

Comment: I have tried as you have written but i still get the same error
"Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.]"

Comment: i plan not to raiserror because i want to handle it in my program and would not like the website to enter a error page which a user would not be able to understand

Comment: Does this happen when you are falling into `CATCH` or when everything is ok?

Comment: `i want to handle it in my program` so do handle it in your program - catch this error and deside what to do after.